# asp.net insert HTML from Code Behind page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I've got a problem with ASP.NET.
I'm using C#.

With a SQL query i have the number exactly of rows in a Database, i need to write the same number of div tag to show the results.

This is the code

count is a variable that contain the number of rows.

Projects is a List

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    form1.Controls.Add(new Literal() { 
         ID = "ltr" + i,

         Text = "<div class= 'container' >Name = " + Projects[i].Name + " ;</div>" });
}
```

But there is a problem, i must place these div into another div with ID = Container.

in this way Literal controls aren't placed into div#Container

How can i do to place the For results into a div?

Comment: Can you display what the expected HTML outcome would look like?

Comment: With PHP the result it this http://d.pr/i/QMWe

in this case count = 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `Literal` control, which is designed to render text, not html tags, you can use either `HtmlGenericControl`:

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl();
div.ID = "div" + i;
div.TagName = "div";
div.Attributes["class"] = "container";
div.InnerText = string.Format("Name = {0} ;", Projects[i].Name);
form1.Controls.Add(div);
```

or `Panel` control, which is rendered into div, with `Literal` inside it:

```
Panel div = new Panel();
div.ID = "panel" + i;
div.CssClass = "container";    
div.Controls.Add(new Literal{Text = string.Format("Name = {0} ;", Projects[i].Name)});    
form1.Controls.Add(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead U Should Use Repeater Control, it'll be quite easy to work with.

Steps

1. Take a SqlDatasource.
2. Take a repeater Control.
3. Set its datasource to .
4. Design the itemTemplate as you like.
5. Done..!

If have any doubt follow this [LINK](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/repeater-control-example-in-aspnet.html)